# Inside Power Apps, when the Form call the DataSource and when it loads already loaded item

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapps-forms

I have 2 SharePoint lists:-

1. Setup
2. Expiry

and each list have a Numeric column which store the Id of the related list. For example the Setup item has a column named "RealtedformId" to store the related expiry item, and the same case applied to the expiry item.

Now inside Power Apps >> i have 2 screens, as follow:-

1. **Expiry screen.** Contain a button named "Go to Setup form" to access the related "Setup Form" + Form to add/edit the Expiry Item.
2. **Setup screen.**  Contain a button named "Go to Expiry form" to access the related "Expiry Form" + Form to add/edit the Setup Item.

now i am confused on when Power Apps will call SharePoint to get the form item, and when it will show the already loaded item inside the form.

For example inside the Expiry screen, we have:-

1- The expiry form has this formula, inside its Item property:-

```
If(varExpiryID>0 ,LookUp('Expiry Form',ID=varExpiryID),If(!IsBlank(varSetupID),LookUp('Expiry Form',RealtedFormID=varSetupID)))
```

2- The "Go to Setup form" button has this onselect property:-

```
If(ExpiryForm.Mode=FormMode.Edit,EditForm(SetUpForm));
If(ExpiryForm.Mode=FormMode.New,NewForm(SetUpForm));
If(ExpiryForm.Mode=FormMode.View,ViewForm(SetUpForm));
If(!IsBlank(varExpiryID),Set(varSetupID,LookUp('SetUp Form',RealtedFormID=varExpiryID).ID));
Navigate(SetUpScreen)
```

And for example inside the Setup screen:-

1- The Setup form has this formula, inside its Item property:-

```
If(varSetupID>0 ,LookUp('SetUp Form',ID=varSetupID),If(!IsBlank(varExpiryID),LookUp('SetUp Form',RealtedFormID=varExpiryID)))
```

2- The "Go to Expiry form" button has this onselect property:-

```
If(SetUpForm.Mode=FormMode.Edit,EditForm(ExpiryForm));
If(SetUpForm.Mode=FormMode.New,NewForm(ExpiryForm));
If(SetUpForm.Mode=FormMode.View,ViewForm(ExpiryForm));
If(!IsBlank(varSetupID),Set(varExpiryID,LookUp('Expiry Form',RealtedFormID=varSetupID).ID));
Navigate(ExpiryScreen)
```

and inside the Setup form we have this Submit button, which submits both forms:-

```
SubmitForm(ExpiryForm);
SubmitForm(SetUpForm);
```

now I have this scenario: -

1. When I edit an expiry item >> the power apps will obviously get the item from the expiry SharePoint list >> I modify some fields inside the expiry form>> click on "Go to setup form">> the power apps will obviously get the item from the setup SharePoint list, at this stage everything is understandable.
   Now if at this stage when I am inside the setup screen >> I click on "Go to expiry form" >> the changes I made to the expiry form will stay showing, so why click on the "Go to Expiry form" did not load the expiry form from the Datasource again? same thing happen if I am inside the setup form and I made some changes >> click on "Go to expiry form" >> the  back to "Go to setup form">> the changes I made to the setup form will stay showing (although I have not submit any form yet).. so how power app internally handles this? I mean when does power apps call the Datasource and when does it load the item which have already been loaded?